# SSRS dynamic change the report header textbox value based on tablix row group value change

Tags: reporting-services

I'm writing a SSRS report contains 2 datasets:

**CustomerAddressDS** : select customer_id, customer_name, customer_address from tbl_customer_address where customer_id = @Internal_Parameter_Customer_ID

**CustomerOrderDS** : select customer_id, order_date, order_number from tbl_customer_orders where order_date = @Parameter_OrderDate

For some reason, I could not join both CustomerAddressDS and CustomerOrderDS into one SQL.

In the report, 2 parameters are set:

**@Parameter_OrderDate** are used for user to select a date for CustomerOrderDS

**@Internal_Parameter_Customer_ID** is an internal parameter and the default value will be referring to customer_id of dataset CustomerOrderDS

The report layout should be like:

```
In Report Header    
Customer ID    
Customer Name   
Customer Address

(Customer ID, Customer Name, Customer Address) are put into one textbox by using expression.

In Report Body:
A tablix bound to CustomerOrderDS to store the customer's daily orders :

 ORDER DATE          ORDER NUMBER
 YYYY-MM-DD                 XXXXX

 Total of the date:         XXXXX
```

The tablix is grouped by the customer ID and will be page break when changing customer ID. My question is that when changing customer ID in the tablix, how could I make the Customer ID/Name/Address on the report header changed? It seems aggregate function in the report header could not help in my case.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I needed data in the header that was related to a table. Unfortunately, since the header is not in the grouped area, this is not possible.

One way is to not use a header and create a header at the top of your table inside the group so it changes with your grouping.

Another way that I ended up using was to use the **Global Page Name** variable in the header (`=Globals!PageName`) and setting the Page Name property on the table.

[image]

You'd have a **Page Name** like:

```
=Fields!Customer_ID.Value & VBCRLF & 
 Fields!Customer_Name.Value & VBCRLF & 
 Fields!Customer_Address.Value
```

The VBCRLF is for a new line (**V**isual **B**asic **C**arriage **R**eturn **L**ine **F**eed).

Comment: For your another way to do that,the Page Name property on the table <- this table is referring to CustomerAddressDS? That means I still need to put both CustomerAddressDS  and CustomerOrderDS  into the report body? Can I just put one table CustomerOrderDS into the report body but still can do the trick? Thanks.