# ssrs - how to use a group by in the header

Tags: reporting-services

My aim is to have that

[image]

I want to add a colum name, on my header that will be in a group. That column name will be linked to an existing group within the body of my report

This is what I've done

[image]

I tried to put a column name inside of a textbox , within the header

```
=(Fields!EVENEMENTS_TYPE_LIBEL.Value, "DataSetEvtsLibel")
```

It did not work. The only thing possible is to have an agreggate (see below)

```
=First(Fields!EVENEMENTS_TYPE_LIBEL.Value, "DataSetEvtsLibel")
```

I then created a parameter `Libel`, I've used a query to provide available values inside of the parameter.

It gives me the relevant field but alas it does not do the grouping.

I looked at the internet but I did not find anything relevant.

If you have any tips, they are more than welcomed.

Thanks

**Update**: Should I mention I'm talking about **Page header**

Comment: Is `EVENEMENTS_TYPE` field a row parent group in your tablix?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta http://i.stack.imgur.com/UdGdW.png

Comment: This dataset is different to the dataset that you use in the tablix to show col1, col2, col3, col4 and col5 columns?

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta this will do the trick `SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,EVENEMENTS_TYPE.LIBEL AS 'EVENEMENTS_TYPE.LIBEL' FROM EVENEMENTS_TYPE INNER JOIN EVENEMENTS ON EVENEMENTS_TYPE.IU_EVT_TYPE = EVENEMENTS.IU_EVT_TYPE WHERE EVENEMENTS.GESTDEL = 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `Group Header` in order to show the current value in the header between each instance of your group.

In the Row Groups pane, right click `Details` group, and add a parent group.

[image]

Select `EVENEMENTS_TYPE_LIBEL` in the group by drop down list, and mark the `Add group header` check box.

[image]

Now in the tablix delete the first row and the first column. You should get a tablix like this:

[image]

Merge the first row in one cell and use `EVENEMENTS_TYPE_LIBEL` field.

Add the columns in the next row, you will have to insert an additional row for column headers, so use insert inside the group:

[image]

It should produce the following tablix:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Adding textbox with the current group present in the page.

See the header textbox properties in the tablix and look for the textbox name:

[image]

Now in the Page Header textbox use:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox176.Value
```

It will show something like this:

[image]

Hope this be what you are looking for.

Comment: my explanation is probably badly written but this is what I have http://i.stack.imgur.com/MGGab.png

Comment: @AndyK, So you want to add the a textbox in the page header with the groups present in that page?

Comment: @AndyK, I think it is possible if you have only one group by page. are you ok with that?

Comment: actually, one group per page in the page header would be great @alejandro-zuleta

Comment: days are long and thanks to you, it is done now. Thank you. IOU

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you would like to dynamic change the report header value based on tablix row group value change.

If the answer is **YES**, you may refer to [SSRS dynamic change the report header textbox value based on tablix row group value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666349/ssrs-dynamic-change-the-report-header-textbox-value-based-on-tablix-row-group-va)

Actually, I have a SSRS report needed to do that. And the answer provided by @Hannover Fist solved my issue.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi @tinySimonh, I'm looking to have a column on the **page header**, not the header of a tablix ...

Comment: @TinySimonH, This approach would work if only one group is present in each page, otherwise it will show only the first group value, that's why I asked Andy if each page show information about only one group.

Comment: @AndyK, you want the [@Libel] textbox display the value of the Tablix Header, right?

Comment: @TinySimonH not only the tablix header but also within the page header

Comment: @AndyK, I see, then Alejandro's solution should have solved your issue.