# SSRS custom code issue

Tags: reporting-services, custom-code

I am working on a SSRS report which has a Table with 2 groups. Used custom code to store the outer group data and display it in the header. This works great for most of the data. However, found couple of instances where the last page of the group( A group can run into multiple pages and there is a page break at the start of each group) is displaying the data of the next group in the header. When I display the stored group data in the group footer, the group details are correct. Confused as to why the header is displaying incorrect data for a few groups. Any pointers as to why this is happening?

Custom code:

```
Public Shared Dim field as String
  Public function Set field(ByVal Val as String)
  field1 = Val
End Function
```

Expression in Outer group to save the group data:

```
=Code.Setfield(field name)
```

Expression to display the saved group data in Header:

```
=Code.field1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your report XML?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding group variable and using PageName property.

Set the group variable as a concatenation of the group fields that I required. Set PageName to the group variable.

In the header use Globals!PageName to access the group data. Spilt the concatenated values using the split function.

Thanks!

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666349/ssrs-dynamic-change-the-report-header-textbox-value-based-on-tablix-row-group-va